# Display subelement while hovering over element

Tags: javascript, html, css, opacity

I'm wondering how to appropriately write css to do the following, I have the following html code:

```
<div class="class1">
   Hello
   <div style="opacity:0" class="class2">
      World
   </div>
</div>
```

When I hover over class 1, I want to change class2's opacity to 1. How would I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the inline style and create a css rule for class2. Then change the opacity when hovering over class1.

```
.class2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

.class1:hover .class2 {
    opacity: 1
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zC8Wc/

**edit**

The inline style has been removed because you can't override them in your CSS without using the `!important` rule which you should absolutely try to avoid. Also all your styling should be in stylesheets not in your HTML.

Comment: Upvoted for using simple CSS, and at least stating the requirement for removing the inline styles. Though you, *also*, don't explain *why* it should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

in css:

```
.class1:hover .class2{
    opacity:1;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/markasoftware/BD66q/

Comment: That won't work, as-written because the in-line styles of the child element will override everything else, as you clearly understand since, in your demo, you've used `!important`, but you've omitted it here). You should explain why `!important` is necessary and how it can be avoided (and it really, *really* should be avoided where possible).

Comment: in the jsfiddle i have `!important`, but yes, in production you'd need to fix that

Comment: Yes; as I clearly stated in my previous comment. The problem is you offer no explanation of *why*, and you don't have it here *in your answer*.

Comment: I was just trying to have the first answer :) and the question asks for how to achieve this effect, and this is the correct concept and I'm not trying to be confusing

Comment: But it's also *wrong* (because it's incomplete), and being **first** is far less important than being **right**.

Comment: I've seen many, many very good answers that barely explain anything but have a complete demo. Also, I don't want to focus too much on other issues with his/her code and more with the concept of how to do this. Let's say somebody's having issues with closures, and they are missing a major concept and are also missing semicolons. You don't focus on that they're missing semicolons, you focus on that they put variables in the wrong scope or whatever the main idea is.

Answer (score 0):

use visibility instead

```
<div class="class1" onmouseover="show_div()">Hello

<div style="visibility:hidden;" class="class2">
 World

</div>
</div>

<script>
function show_div()
{
document.getElementsByClassName("class2")[0].style.visibility="visible"

}
</script>
```

Comment: You realise that won't work, right? And the reason it won't work is because a `nodeList` doesn't have a `style` property (you have to iterate over the elements in the returned `nodeList` one-by-one to adjust their `style` individually).

Comment: yes you are right , sorry i didnt pay attention that the second div was a child , anyway let me fix this.

Comment: Because for *many* tasks it's unnecessary. Certainly this one is easy enough without it (and doesn't even require the addition of an `id` to the element).

Comment: Further, in plain JavaScript: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lp52S/) (yes, it's more verbose, but hardly complex)